# javascript toggleClass only working on one set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built my portfolio website, so that you can hide/show different categories of my work - branding, art etc.

To do this I have created hide/show buttons, and have animated a cross X to rotate 45degrees into a plus + to indicate whether clicking it will hide or show the categories respectively. Hope that makes sense.

I've used the following code for this purpose

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
            $("#buttonDigital").click(function() {
                $(".DigitalImg").toggleClass("DigitalImg-change");
            });
        });
```

HTML - note the button is contained in categories-desktop div (to be visible only on larger screen sizes):

```
<div id="categories-desktop">
    <div id="buttonDigital" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="$('.brick.digital').toggle();">
                        <p>DIGITAL</p>
                        <img class="DigitalImg" src="img/button/x.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #buttonDigital {
    width: 180px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #ff644b;
}
    .DigitalImg {
    position: relative;
    right: -158px;
    top: -16px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

 .DigitalImg-change {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: 0.2s ease-out;
 }
```

You can see an example of where I'm up to at [www.jackwatson.co.uk](http://www.jackwatson.co.uk)

When the site is displayed on screen sizes of width lower than 855px, I would like the buttons to take up the whole width of the screen and only appear above each category as you scroll down the page (each project taking up the full width of the screen also).

I have copied and pasted the same buttons and put them in divs to be displayed at this small screen size only:

```
<div id="categories-mobile">
                    <div id="buttonDigital" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="$('.brick.digital').toggle();">
                        <p>DIGITAL</p>
                        <img class="DigitalImg" src="img/button/x.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

However the javascript that makes the X rotate transition seems to stop working at this point, and I'm really not sure why.

I'm definitely a noob, so it's likely a stupid question, and I appreciate your time to look at this and would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: IDs must be unique, you've duplicated ID `buttonDigital`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should only use unique ID's so if you change the #buttonDigital to a class based selector .buttonDigital then remove or change the id so each div is unique and add the class to them should work.

hope it helps

```
$(function() {
        $(".buttonDigital").click(function() {
            $(".DigitalImg").toggleClass("DigitalImg-change");
        });
    });
```

then the html would look like (you would want to use -1,-2,-4 so that each button is unique. you could also remove the id unless you need it elsewhere

```
 <div id="buttonDigital-1" class='buttonDigital' style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="$('.brick.digital').toggle();">
                    <p>DIGITAL</p>
                    <img class="DigitalImg" src="img/button/x.png">
                </div>
```